# error while spec.setContent(Intent) on tabSpace

Tags: android-tabhost

There is an error while i am putting Intent as `spec.setContent(Intent);` on tabSpace,and it works fine if i put a layout on `spec.setContent(tab1);`

And following is the error:-

> did you forget to call 'public void setup(localactivitymanager
>   activitygroup)

Here is the class:-

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

    Point size;
    RelativeLayout r1;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Context context;
    TabHost.TabSpec spec_signin,spec_signup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        context = getApplicationContext();

       Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(),R.drawable.accont_bannre),size.x,size.y,true);
        Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
        r1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.r1);
        r1.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

        TabHost host = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        host.setup();

        //Tab 1
        spec_signin = host.newTabSpec("SIGNIN");
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        spec_signin.setContent(songsIntent);
        spec_signin.setIndicator("SIGN IN", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.active_arrow));
      //  spec_signin.setIndicator("SIGNIN");
         host.addTab(spec_signin);

        //Tab 2
        spec_signup = host.newTabSpec("SIGNUP");
        Intent Intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        spec_signup.setContent(Intent);
        spec_signup.setIndicator("SIGN UP", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.active_arrow));
        // spec_signup.setIndicator("SIGNUP");
        host.addTab(spec_signup);

    }//oncreate ends
}
```

and the XML:-`<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/r2">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/r1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="270dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <View
                        android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
                        android:id="@+id/v1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#ccc7c7"/>
                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:background="#dede"
                android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>`
`

Answer (score 0):

i have added following lines and it running.

```
LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);

    host.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
```